# Interface object seen in Spring batch Job launcher? how?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

`public interface JobLauncher {
public JobExecution run(Job job, JobParameters jp) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException;
}`

This is a part of spring framework JobLauncher i/f
The method run has to be implemented by an implementing class.

Does "job" in run(Job job, JobParameters jp) represents an object of interface Job? but with Java's logic you cannot create object of any interface..

Please explain with an example using Job interface...

Answer (score 0):

> Does "job" in run(Job job, JobParameters jp) represents an object of
>   interface Job? but with Java's logic you cannot create object of any
>   interface..

You are right, you cannot instantiate an Interface. The reason the parameter is `Job` is so that you can pass the method any object that `implements` the interface `Job`. You can create multiple Job objects with each of them doing different things and use the **one** JobLauncher to launch them.

You can use a `JobBuilderFactory` to create a Job that can include many steps.
A good example of this can be found here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

```
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
}
```

Using the above will create a `FlowJob` object in Spring which will be compatible with JobLauncher's run method as it implements `Job`.

Comment: I want to know:-  what to write in return statement of class implementing interface JobLauncher's run method